# I have a function that needs to use emails that are within a cell range on my sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a function for Google Sheets that sends an email based on whether or not a cell value has a particular variable in it. Every part of the below code works more or less as intended except for the part where it needs an email recipient to send the email. I know where the problem is, I'm just not experienced with code at all (sorry in advance) and don't know how to fix this.

The error:
Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient
(anonymous) @ Untitled.gs:15
sendEmails  @ Untitled.gs:5

Thank you for your patience.

```js
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Emails'); // change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet
  const data = sh.getRange('A2:D'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  data.forEach(r=>{
     let sendemailValue = r[1];  
     if (sendemailValue === "X"){
       let lrow=sh.getLastRow();
         let name = r[0];
         let amount = r[2];
         let item = r[3];
         let emailAddress = r[4];
         let message = 'Hello ' + name + ', your receipt is ' + amount + ' for your ' + item;
         let subject = 'Your Receipt.'
         MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
     }
  });  
}
```

Comment: Questions: Are you getting any error messages that might be helpful? What is the value of `emailAddress` after you initialize it: you can find this by going `console.log(emailAddress)`?

Comment: Here's the error message, not sure if it's helpful, but I'll add it to the original question as I forgot to do that. 

Error 
Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient
(anonymous) @ Untitled.gs:15
sendEmails @ Untitled.gs:5

Comment: From your error I'd guess that column 5 has no email address in it.

Comment: Assuming column E is column 5, yes, there are email addresses in this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wish to consider an addition like this:

```
if(emailAddress) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
} else {
  console.log(`Row: ${i + 2}`);//and add ( ,i) to the forEach
}
```

also change this:

```
const data = sh.getRange('A2:D'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

to this:

```
const data = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow()-1,5).getValues();
```

I increased the number of columns and changed the format to insure it will not return a bunch of nulls at the bottom.  But now that I think about it the problem was probably that you are looking for the emailaddress outside of the range of you data.

Altogether:

```
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Emails'); // change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet
  const data = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 5).getValues();
  data.forEach((r,i) => {
    let sendemailValue = r[1];
    if (sendemailValue === "X") {
      let lrow = sh.getLastRow();
      let name = r[0];
      let amount = r[2];
      let item = r[3];
      let emailAddress = r[4];//this is column 5
      let message = 'Hello ' + name + ', your receipt is ' + amount + ' for your ' + item;
      let subject = 'Your Receipt.'
      if(emailAddress) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      } else {
        console.log(`Row: ${i + 2}`);//will let you know what row it's failing on
      }
    }
  });
}
```